# Google recaptcha грузит сайт

Tags: recaptcha, pagespeed-insights, google-recaptcha

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключение капчи:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Почему капча так сильно влияет на скорость?

Comment: Это из какого инструмента? Google Insights?

Comment: Да, с Google Insights.
Может ли быть это из за того что на одной странице находится 5 разных форм с капчей?

Answer (score 4):

Каптча подгружает свои скрипты с других серверов и это занимает определенное время. Есть несколько решений данной проблемы.
1. Инициировать каптчу только на страницах где она нужна.
2. Вызывать ее только когда пользователь взаимодействует с формой.

Казалось бы второй вариант идеален (хоть и сложен в исполнении) но таким образом каптча получает недостаточно данных о пользователе и пропускает некоторых ботов принимая их за пользователей.

Пример решения по варианту 2 можно почитать тут https://tehnoblog.org/google-invisible-recaptcha-how-to-boost-lighthouse-performance-score/